# How can I make anywhere on a webpage clickable and navigate to an address without making the entire page a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I am trying to make this website http://quoteswag.ga click through to a random quote just by clicking anywhere on the whitespace or on the quote, but I don't want to have it seem like it is a link with the mouse hand and url status etc for aesthetic purposes. I have searched for a way to do this with javascript, but can't find the correct solution.

I just want the page to navigate to /random whenever a user click on whitespace or the quote, or the div enclosing the whitespace and/or quote div.

I'm assuming this won't be too hard with javascript or jquery, but I'm not a pro at these at all. Thanks.

Comment: Bind click event to the document/body/div or whatever you want. If your question is about how to bind click event, then obviously you didn't put enough effort to resolve your expected behaviour...

Comment: In fact, sounds like you want just on quote click, load a random new quote without reloading the entire page, is it?

Comment: @A.Wolff yes that would be ideal, but it seems the first answer hit it spot on. Yeah I'm still getting my head around javascript and my searches were bringing up much more complex things.

Comment: I would alter @Barth Zalewski's answer slightly, to use a delegated event handler. This will be more efficient and also work with dynamic content (as a bonus) e.g. `$(document).on('click', '.redirection', function() { window.location.href = 'http://...'; });`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I made the suggested changes and all is working well. I'll have to research more about 'delegated event handlers' in regards to efficiency and dynamic content.

Comment: For any mouse events, delegated event handlers are quicker to connect and have zero *noticeable* effect on the events when the occur. You would have to click 50,000 times a second to notice anything so it's win-win with delegated events :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to be as easy as adding

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$('.redirection').click(function() { window.location.href = 'http://...'; });
</script>
```

And to add the class `redirection` to all clickable elements. Or, alternatively, to apply the event to **all** elements:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).click(function() { window.location.href = 'http://...'; });
</script>
```

Please be aware, that using the latter one applies the effect even to things like the logo, the footer etc.

Comment: So your solution is to add potentially 1000s of instances of a class and as many click handlers... hmmm. Not such a great idea when a single handler on `document` can do the same thing using event bubbling (and checking e.target) :)

Comment: It depends on the structure. I believe the OP has enough intelligence to decide which selector to use. If he generates the elements with PHP or Angular, for example, it would be Peanuts. For manual usage, not.

Comment: Even with generation that is still a large potential page bloat, for no reason as `document` can handle it all with a single handler (and no extra classes).

Comment: I have changed my answer....

Comment: I've implemented this answer (the first part with the "redirection" class on the quote-container div and the quote div) and it seems to be doing the trick. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Your second option can of course check for what is clicked, so you *do* have control over it. You could also use a *delegated event handler* for your first option (which will be more efficient).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie just want to let you know that the original `$('.redirection').click(function()` seems to work also on mobile also when users tap the screen, whereas your suggested `$(document).on('click', '.redirection', function()` does not seem to work on mobile when I tested.

Comment: @phocks: There is no reason delegated click handlers should *not* work on mobile. I use them all the time on cross platform apps with zero problems. I assume you are using a later version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

From your website source, there is a `div` with class named `container container-quote` this div should be a hyper link as follows:

```
<a href="#">
   <div class="container container-quote">.....
   </div>
</a>
```

Then you have to apply the following CSS:

```
<style>
 a:link, .container.container-quote *{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
   cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/xevejuvohe/1/

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion that I had thought of, except I think I prefer the javascript solutions above, as the cursor still turns into the text bar when it hovers over the quote text. I guess you could style that with css too. Maybe I'll implement this later on as it will be more compatible with non-javascript enabled browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.onclick = function (e) {
                        window.open("http://www.google.nl", "_blank");
                        return false;
        };
    </script>
```